# SQL: Football match table structure

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, match

First of all sorry for my english. Anyway, I designed a database for soccer leagues, I have a doubt about the **MATCH** table.
The obvious way is to add two fields for *home team id* and for *away team id*, and a foreign key for each. But this way I think is not the best way, because , for  example, if I want to get all the MATCH played by a team I have to write a *where* with two fields instead of one.

So my solution are two and I want to ask you what do you think:

1. Create a *ManyToMany* table **MATCHES_TEAMS** and keep the two fields *away/home team id* or one of them in **MATCH** table.
2. Create two *ManyToMany* table **MATCHES_HOME_TEAMS** and **MATCHES_AWAY_TEAMS**.

Thank you and goodbye

Comment: Someone on the stack had a decent answer for this in the last year. I will look or you can [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bmysql%5dhome%20team) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bmysql%5dhome%20team%20away) or a similar search

Comment: Thank you but I didn't find nothing

Comment: There are dozens of questions with accepted answers and comment threads http://stackoverflow.com/q/32552455 ... you just have to actually look thru a dozen or so and not be lazy about it.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36822336

Answer (score 0):

Hw about a table for teams and a table for matches with a flag (H or A) to denote home of away?

Comment: It's like my first solution, with a _manytomany_ table and one or two fields which indicate home or away team but I don't know if this will introduce too much redundancy.

Comment: Now I am thinking that maybe we are thinking in the wrong way, that is *home/away_team_id* is not just a team but something more. For example it is not just a team because have the *score* field, but if we think more deeply the score is unnecessary because it can be calculated by the table _appearance_ which record the score of each team player in the match.